# What is the new openstack cli command for performing a router cleanup?

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

`neutron router-gateway-clear` was to command to use till neutron cli was deprecated:

```
neutron CLI is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use openstack CLI instead.
```

So my question is how to perform a cleanup using the new `openstack` client?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I was able to do this but it did involve a lot of code:

```
  openstack router unset --external-gateway $ROUTER
  for PORT in $(openstack port list --router $ROUTER --format=value -c ID)
  do
    openstack router remove port $ROUTER $PORT
  done
  openstack router delete $ROUTER
```

This became part of the [`osclean`](https://gist.github.com/ssbarnea/db5a0089f48405f9a92d73e2361b87b0) utility that wipes openstack projects based on resource names.